# Pandas: How to add multiple absolute value columns based on a list of reference columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add multiple columns with the absolute values of multiple reference columns. I'd like to pass in a list of reference columns rather than doing it manually.

Given df:

```
 String    Val1   Val2   Val3
 item1     2.00  -2.50  -3.00
 item2    -1.00   1.25  -0.25
```

Desired output:

```
 String    Val1   Val2   Val3   Abs1   Abs2   Abs3
 item1     2.00  -2.50  -3.00   2.00   2.50   3.00
 item2    -1.00   1.25  -0.25   1.00   1.25   0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a List of col names to convert and use this to create the new columns:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'String': ['Item1', 'Item2'],
                  'Val1' : [2.0, -1.0],
                   'Val2' : [-2.5, 1.25],
                    'Val3' : [-3.0, -0.25]
                   })

cols = ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']

# or if you want all original columns use cols = df.columns.tolist()

for name in cols:
    df[name.replace('Val', 'Abs')] = abs(df[name])
          
print(df)

  String  Val1  Val2  Val3  Abs1  Abs2  Abs3
0  Item1   2.0 -2.50 -3.00   2.0  2.50  3.00
1  Item2  -1.0  1.25 -0.25   1.0  1.25  0.25
```

Comment: I edited the OP: there's additional columns in the df, so I think the for loop would need to change right?

Comment: No  - its fine as is. See edited answer,

Answer (score 0):

I created your dataframe using -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 2.00, -2.50, -3.00], [-1.00, 1.25, -0.25]], columns=["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"])
```

And then -

```
desired_cols = df.columns[:3]
# OR desired_cols = ["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]

 df = pd.concat([df, abs(df[desired_cols]).rename(columns={orig:orig.replace("Val", "Abs") for orig in desired_cols})], axis=1)
```

Comment: I edited the OP: there's additional columns in the df, so the full lambda function can't work

Comment: Have modified accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

you can just iterate over your columns adding new column for each one of them and calling `abs()` on the column

```
for column in df.columns:
        df['Abs' + column] = df[column].abs()
```

Comment: This  does not give the new column names required by the OP.

Comment: @user19077881 he didn't state in is questions that he need same names he can use `enumerator` to do so. the answer  give him how to use abs and solves his problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by defining a function to add absolute values of columns to the DataFrame.

```
def add_abs_column(column_num, df):
    df[f'Abs{column_num}'] = df.apply(lambda x: abs(x[f'Val{column_num}']), axis=1)
    return df
```

You can then call this three times to add the absolute value columns to the DataFrame. Complete code below:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': [2.0, -1.0], 'Val2': [-2.5, 1.25], 'Val3': [-3.0, -0.25]})

def add_abs_column(column_num, df):
    df[f'Abs{column_num}'] = df.apply(lambda x: abs(x[f'Val{column_num}']), axis=1)
    return df

for column_num in [1, 2, 3]:
    df = add_abs_column(column_num, df)
```

Produces this:

```
  String  Val1  Val2  Val3  Abs1  Abs2  Abs3
0  Item1   2.0 -2.50 -3.00   2.0  2.50  3.00
1  Item2  -1.0  1.25 -0.25   1.0  1.25  0.25
```

Comment: I edited the OP: there's additional columns in the df, so I think the for loop would need to change right?

Comment: @Primer4662 Nope, no need to change the solution! It only targets the columns 'Val1', 'Val2' and 'Val3' so the solution still works.